# Unexpected PHP error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I get this error why trying out a piece of code:

```
if ( 10 < $pages )
    {
        if ( $currentPage == 1 )
        {
            $i = 1;
            for ( ; do
 {
 $i <= 10; ++$i, )
                {
                    $paging .= "<a href=\"".$frontUrl.$i.$backUrl."\" ".( $i == $currentPage ? " class=\"selected\"" : " class=\"normal\"" ).">".$i."</a>";
                    break;
                }
            } while ( 1 );
        }
```

As you can see, it's for a page script, this is the error it gives me:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/neel/public_html/engine/includes/functions.php on line 35

and I have no idea why I get this. If anyone could help me out, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `for ( ; do  {  $i <= 10; ++$i, )`? What on earth is that monster supposed to mean?

Comment: What the buck is that `for` there?

Comment: With code formatted like that it is not surprising that you are having difficulty debugging it.  Try format your code in an even way.  It'll be easier to debug and easier to read.

Comment: Excuse me for being a noob at php but I have no idea, a friend wrote this out for me.

Comment: *"I have no idea why I get this"*: You get this error because you have an unexpected `,` in line 35 (you have to read the error message). Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php. If your friend wrote this, you should talk to him.

Comment: You need to learn PHP.  You get an error because that code makes no sense.

Comment: **We do not do that**.  If you want to delete your post [flag it for moderator attention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560) and tell them why.  Don't just delete the entire content of your post...

Comment: @Tibor You meant `What the duck is that for here` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have mixed a for loop and a while loop in syntaxicly impossible way!
Either you have to use:

```
for ( $i = 1;  $i <= 10; ++$i) {

}
```

or

```
do {

} while(1);
```

note, the second one is infinity loop, while the first one has exactly 10 iterations

Comment: This question is far too localized.  Please don't encourage these questions by providing an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

It's this part

```
for ( ; do
 {
 $i <= 10; ++$i, )
```

I'm not sure what you want to do.
Why not `for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)` ?

Also, I'm assuming you want a comma after the `$i++`, and also notice that the paranetheses were closed before the curly brace (should be other way around)